# Subform filtering by a ComboBox value

Tags: ms-access

[image: Relationships]It has been quite sometime since I have used access and now I am needing to build a small little database intended to store office information. Who is in them, what room, etc.

tables:
tblRoom
tblBuilding
tblOffice

So I start with a blank form. I add a combobox, I have used the tblRoom room number as the dropdown selection.

I would like a subform that uses the tblOffice information, there are several fields, including room number. I would like to select the room dropdown and in the subform it show me all the rows from tblOffice where it has that room number.

I have gotten a lot of the unbound errors, I have also manually typed in the master/child linking attributed room number, combobox44.roomnumber tblRoom.Roomnumber and many other things trying to link these two together.

I feel this should be extremely easy to do in Access 2016 and I am just not seeing how.

Comment: Is form bound to tblRoom? If so, why would you have a combobox for Room? If purpose of combobox is to find an existing tblRoom record, the combobox must be UNBOUND. More than one office can be in same room?

Comment: I dont understand what you mean. I mean we have offices that have multiple people in it. say we have a room A123, well John Smith used to be in room A123 but now Barbara smith is, so the subform should show essentially all occurences of that selected combobox room in the subform. Does that make sense?

Comment: So are you tracking people or 'offices'? Exactly what is an 'office'? Again, is form bound to tblRoom? If yes, then purpose of combobox should be a search/filter criteria to locate and move to existing room record and should be UNBOUND. Then subform should be bound to tblOffice linking on room PK/FK fields. Alternatively, if form is bound to tblOffice and there is a dropdown to select room then there should not be a subform. Don't understand why tblDept has two links to tblOffice.

Comment: Okay from reading what you said I kind of figured out I think what I needed. I wasnt adding both tables needed to link on the form wizard